# How is an APK file laid out on an Android device after install?

Tags: android, apk

I guess that the APK file is not stored as unpacked on the device after being installed. But then at application runtime is it unpacked to some memory buffer? Or is it stored unpacked at some temporary location?

I'm interested from a point of runtime implications of accessing packaged assets mainly.